# Would the ultimate goal of attaining Moksha lead to extinction of humans?

Tags: moksha, sex, human

Illicit sex is wrong. Even sex in marriage is only for procreation. Sex takes one away from the ultimate goal of Moksha. This materialistic world is a place of suffering and pleasure, but more biased towards suffering. From all these what I infer of is

- in the ideal world would be to not have sex at all, not even for procreation.
- Why bring children into the suffering. Also if humans vanish from earth, it would be a lot less suffering place.
- Isn't it ideal  that everyone becomes Krishna follower and give up on material desires including sex completely.
- If everyone follows this, the final state will lead to extinction of human species (I am not trying to save the species here, I am neutral to what happens to the human species)

I had asked these questions to a devotee already and his answer was this is not practical as all people will not become sanyasis. But my question is not about what is practically achievable. My question is what is the best case scenario if we follow the teachings of Gita.

I am not convinced by the previous answer as it just means that we humans exist mostly because of the deeds of people who are(or were at the time of the act that lead to a new human) ignorant(I do not disagree with this - this probably is real).

I expect logical and unbiased answers. 
Please be aware of "Confirmation bias" while answering.

Do not quote parts which confirms to the side you pick while answering, also recall and cite quotes which go against the side you have picked.

Comment: please read the forum rules. questions asking for opinions are not allowed.

Comment: Reproducing children is our duty. Procreation fulfills our debt to ancestors i.e Pitri Rina. By not producing children, you're effectively denying them their chance to attain moksha.

Comment: One doesn't have to give up sex to be a follower of Krishna.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I think OP is saying about Illicit sex. And for ISKCONItes illicit sex includes having sex for pleasure(even when in marriage).This is one of the four necessary requirements to become Krishna devotee (according to ISKCON ofcourse).

Comment: Sex for pleasure is not illicit i.e. violation of Dharma but it is definitely materialistic i.e. detrimental to spirituality. Sex outside marriage would imply as illicit. But it doesn't mean you have to give up sex altogether. Sex in accordance to Karma Yoga is completely in sync with "Krishna Consciousness". Kama is one of the four Purusharthas (aims of human life). Sex for procreation only, within marriage is never detrimental to Moksha. @RishiX

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury i agree with you. But that's how some ISKCON followers have told me. That they include having sex for pleasure in their defination of Illicit sex.

Comment: "Isn't it ideal that everyone becomes Krishna follower" No. Krishna is just an avatar of Visnhu. Devotion to the atman (such as when Krishna spoke to Arjuna when he was in direct connection to the Iswar) is a goal.

Comment: "My question is what is the best case scenario if we follow the teachings of Gita." - this looks like a hypothetical question; not an objective question that can answered using references.

Answer (score 1):

As Surya said in comments,it is necessary for us to pay our debts to our pitras(ancestors).But most importantly Sri Krishna Himself said in Bhagavad Gita that-

> Of weapons I am the thunderbolt; among cows I am the surabhi. Of causes for procreation I am Kandarpa, the god of love, and of serpents I am Vāsuki.[BG:10.28]

Srila Prabhupada has explained this verse in his commentary

> Kandarpa is the sex desire for presenting good sons; therefore Kandarpa is the representative of Kṛṣṇa. Sometimes sex is engaged in only for sense gratification; such sex does not represent Kṛṣṇa. But sex for the generation of good children is called Kandarpa and represents Kṛṣṇa

So as we can see Kandarpa or sex desire for having good sons/offsprings is the representative of Krishna Himself. Thus a Krishna devotee or one who is aspirant of being Krishna Concious should always follow Krishna's words. Only Sannyasins are allowed to be unmarried but as the other devotee told you, not everyone can become Sannyasins as it is impractical. Thus it is Krishna's will.

Answer (score 0):

I am reproducing the content from the question, for clarity purpose.

> Sex takes one away from the ultimate goal of Moksha. This
>   materialistic world is a place of suffering and pleasure, but more
>   biased towards suffering. From all these what I infer of is
>
> - in the ideal world would be to not have sex at all, not even for procreation.
> - Why bring children into the suffering. Also if humans vanish from earth, it would be a lot less suffering place.
> - Isn't it ideal  that everyone becomes Krishna follower and give up on material desires including sex completely.
> - If everyone follows this, the final state will lead to extinction of human species (I am not trying to save the species here, I am neutral
>     to what happens to the human species)

---

I don't know whether these ideas emerged from the literature of ISKCON or that of OP.  Hence, I am presuming that these ideas are of OP only.

Basically, humans are also animals.  There is no difference between the activities of humans and other living beings, except thinking ability.

The scriptures say

> आहार-निद्रा-भय-मैथुनं च समानमेतत्पशुभिर्नराणाम् । धर्मो हि तेषामधिको
>   विशेषो धर्मेण हीनाः पशुभिः समानाः ॥
>
> "food, sleep, fear and **mating**, these acts of humans are similar to
>   animals'.  Of them (humans), **dharma (right conduct)** is the only
>   special thing, **without dharma humans are also animals**."

---

So sexual impulse is not adharma or illegal or illicit.  However,  what is illegal or illicit sex is a different issue.

Even Rig Veda says gratifying sexual impulse is mandatory, to proceed further in the SPIRITUAL line.

---

In [Rig Veda I.179 (P.100)](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Rigveda_Samhita_English_Vol_II/#book/128), Lopamudra teaches Sage Agasthya the importance of fulfilling sexual desires.

> Lopāmudrā teaches it to her husband who was inclined to asceticism.
>   She says that even those ancients didn't find their end destination
>   who, without their worldly responsibilities, just toiled and spoke the
>   Ṛta.
>
> They had to marry, they had to speak their experience, they had to
>   live their life to find the meaning and to achieve the success.
>
> Lopāmudrā says to her ascetically inclined husband that this way of
>   invoking hardship on her by staying away from her doesn't make Agastya
>   complete. He has to fulfill his life before thinking of achieving
>   success in spiritual journey. Passion is responsible for synthesis and
>   guilt is responsible for deconstruction. One who has understood the
>   way to deconstruct and construct achieve the right plane of existence.
>
> Agastya, on hearing the wise words of his wife, rebuilds the kāma in
>   him and returns to his life, his duties.

---

Finally, about the last query: **If everyone follows this, the final state will lead to extinction of human species**.

Please don't worry about extinction of humans :-), as Sri Krishna said in BG 7.3 as follows:

> मनुष्याणां सहस्रेषु कश्िचद्यतति सिद्धये।
>
> यततामपि सिद्धानां कश्िचन्मां वेत्ति तत्त्वतः।।7.3।।
>
> Among thousands of men, perchance, one makes effort for the determined
>   knowledge. Among those, having the determined knowledge-even though
>   they make effort-perchance one realises Me correctly.

Out of billions of humans, only a handful of few will get liberation, at any given point of time.  And, it will take a longer period for remaining people getting liberation.

Finally, it is the creation of the God.  That God will take care of extinction issue also.